# PHP Output from mysql database is blank

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this PHP page which accepts 3 items and stores into a database. The output of the results fetched from database is blank. I can see the records being saved in database via phpmyadmin. What's wrong with this code?

This is the code that displays results in a table.

```
// Add a shortcode to display the employee's attendance record
function attendance_record_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'employee_attendance';

    // Get the employee ID from the shortcode parameters
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'employee_id' => ''
    ), $atts );
    $employee_id = $atts['employee_id'];

    // Get the employee's attendance data from the database
    $attendance_data = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE employee_id = %d",
            $employee_id
        )
    );

    // Display the attendance data in a table
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $attendance_data as $attendance ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $attendance->date; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $attendance->status; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'attendance_record', 'attendance_record_shortcode' );
```

This is the code that accepts input and saves data to database.

```
// Create the attendance page and display the attendance form
function attendance_page() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'employee_attendance';

    // If the form has been submitted, add the attendance data to the database
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit_attendance'] ) ) {
        $employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
        $date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['date'] ) );
        $status = $_POST['status'];
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'employee_id' => $employee_id,
                'date' => $date,
                'status' => $status
            )
        );
    }

    // Display the attendance form
    ?>
    <h1>Employee Attendance</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="employee_id">Employee ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" required>
        <br>
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
        <br>
        <label for="status">Status</label>
        <select name="status" id="status">
            <option value="present">Present</option>
            <option value="absent">Absent</option>
            <option value="late">Late</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_attendance" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

[phpMyAdmin Database Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZXuT.png)

[Blank Output Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R3gn.png)

Comment: I think you need to `debug the prefix variable of the database and employee_id` which pass inside where query. All code looks perfect.

Comment: Replace "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE employee_id = %d" to "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE employee_id = %d" or better 'SELECT * FROM '. $table_name .'WHERE employee_id = %d'.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But it didn't work. I don't see any error in the code but the output is just blank.